# Entry point in ollydbg is not according to ImageBase value in PE

Tags: windows-7, portable-executable, ollydbg

I am new to PE analysis, so please bear with me for my basis question.
Loading PE in Windows XP and Windows 7 are showing different Entry Point

Hello.exe created in Windows XP.

CFF Explorer is showing **ImageBase** **0x00400000** and **AddressOfEntryPoint** **0x00001578**. But when I load hello.exe in **OllyDbg (running on Windows 7)**, it is showing **EP** at **0x773201C8**

When I load hello.exe in **OllyDbg (running on Windows XP)**, its showing the correct **EP** at **0x00401578**.

I would like to know why the **EP** is different on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Address OF Entry Point in PeHeader is an RVA (Relative Virtual Address)

it is relative to the Imagebase

```
C:\>dumpbin /headers c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe | grep -iE "entry|im.*base"
           12D6C entry point (01012D6C) _WinMainCRTStartup
         1000000 image base (01000000 to 010BFFFF)
```

Image base can be different for different loads ( Read Upon ASLR Address Space layout Randomization )

so you are seeing these differences